# Storing reference data in client onload of browser page in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

EDIT: I am rephrasing my question again :)

I have an Web Application that uses AngularJS as a client framework. I am currently loading a set of reference data (dependant data sets like Country, State, Region, Codes etc) on every page load. Is there a better way to make the server calls and store the data in a cache. At what point in the Angular life cycle do I make these calls to retrieve and store data?

Comment: When first page load, init your api call once and store the data inside some service/factory.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to do that. You can make a init call to your api as your page gets loads, and then save the data wherever you want.You can save them using localstorage,sessionstorage, factory, service,constants etc.